# Documenting a DRF GET endpoint with multiple responses using Swagger

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, serialization, drf-yasg

I have a GET endpoint for a RESTful API I am creating using Django.
This endpoint reads three values from the URL's query string. A particular parameter in the query string has the potential to change the data (include extra fields and change the structure slightly) which is returned in the JSON response from this endpoint.

This endpoint is not tied directly to a single model. My view subclasses `RetrieveAPIView`, in the view, I override the `get_object` method and some logic is performed to query multiple models, make some decisions and return an ordered dictionary.

My problem is as follows:

I would like to document this endpoint using Swagger. I am using `drf-yasg` to generate my Swagger documentation. I have no serializers declared for this view; since I manually construct an ordered dictionary in `get_object` I don't see the purpose of declaring one. I'm not sure how to document my endpoint using `drf-yasg`.

I have discovered only one approach to document the endpoint, but it is quite ugly and bloats my code, and I'm wondering if there is a better approach.

By declaring an `openapi.Response` object, and supplying this object to the `@swagger_auto_schema` decorator Swagger displays the two possible responses, but describing the entire response really bloats my code. Here is an example if what currently works to document the endpoint:

```
class View(RetrieveAPIView):

    http_method_names = ['get']

    response_json = {
        'Response if X query parameter is something': {
            'key1': 'string',
            'key3': {
                'key4': 0,
                'key5': 'string',
                'key6': 'string'
            }
        },
        'Response if X query parameter is something else': {
            'key1': 'string',
            'key2': 'string'
        }
    }
    swagger_get_responses = openapi.Response(description='Description for the set of responses',
                                             examples=response_json)

    @swagger_auto_schema(responses={200: swagger_get_responses})
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(request, args, kwargs)

    def get_object(self):
        // Execute a method on a model that queries other models, performs some logic, and 
        // then returns an ordered dict which is then returned by this function.
```

Is there a better approach to this problem? Is there a better Django design pattern/feature of the Django framework or drf-yasg library that I can apply here that will help me handle multiple response bodies?

Comment: The docs generators need some sort if schema to generate the documentation. Else they wouldn't have anyway of knowing the format of input/output to document and you would have to do that manually. Usually, DRF based libs like drf-yasg use the serializers as schemas but then you are not using serializers. If you're fields are always dynamically generated depending on request, then maybe you're better of going with graphql? In any case, for now I see no alternative than doing it manually

Comment: An option could be to use serializers and implement the logic for the dynamic fields in it. In this way, your API will be more structured and more easily documented. There are existing packages for dynamic serializers like https://github.com/dbrgn/drf-dynamic-fields or you could implement yours

Comment: Thanks so much for your insight @Ken4scholars , using serializers and implementing the logic for the dynamic fields would probably be the simplest solution. However writing some entirely new code, and introducing a serializer purely for the purpose of documenting my API seems like a poor approach. You seem to be suggesting creating a single serializer to handle both types of response bodies, but from what I understand I would have to declare two separate serializers to overcome this issue, as having all my validation in a single serializer would result in the same problem with documentation.

Comment: Like I suggested, the serializers are more flexible and would generally improve the structure of your code instead of manually add fields to a dictionary. But then, you can choose to manually write the docs. I suggested using implementing a serializer that can yield dynamic fields so you won't have to define several serializers. Check the link I sent and see how they implement such serializers